# Practices for checking correctness of uploaded files in zend framework 1.9

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm currently trying to get an upload screen in a php application (in combination with zend framework 1.9) up and running.

I know how to do the upload itself and also do some basic validations of the files.

What I am wondering is, what are common methods to ensure that the file has been uploaded correctly.

I have looked through the validator examples (especially the MD5 one). Example:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
$upload->addValidator('Md5', false, '3b3652f336522365223');
```

But from how I understand it you would already need to know what MD5 SHOULD be the result.
Thus the user would have to put that info into the upload screen so that it can be transmitted alongside the file (it could be that I'm mistaken there though).

So my question is: Is there any way in zend-framework how I can validate files without having any need for additional inputs from the user (in addition to the file itself)?
Or what are the practices used there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for such a thing in my opinion.  This is the responsibility of the [TCP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), web browser, and PHP engine.

TCP guarantees that packets received by a server are the same as they were when sent by a client.  Web browsers are tested to ensure that HTTP uploads are handled properly such that files are uploaded correctly and similarly PHP is tested such that it guarantees HTTP file uploads are saved to the server with the same contents that were uploaded.

Doing something like this is just extra work and will likely never result in an error.  To do this you'd likely have to use new HTML5 features that allow Javascript to read local files, then implement some hash function in JS so clients would have to have HTML5 capable browsers supporting the file APIs and.